# Is it possible to make an array which reference to a picture

Tags: java, android, arrays, eclipse

So I have this class "MakePhoto". And it can make and save a photo. Now I want to save the pictures in an array. So when you make a picture, it should store it in in array[0] and the second picture should be stored in array[1] etc. So array[0] should reference to the first picture which is made. Is this somehow possible?

PhotoMaker.java class:

```
package com.example.photoviewer;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import com.example.keyfinder.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class FotoMaker extends Activity 
    { 
    ImageView iv;
    Uri uriOfPicture;


    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_pic);

        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        { 


            @Override 
            public void onClick (View v){
                takeImageFromCamera();

            } 
        }); 
        } 
        @Override 
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
        { 
            if(requestCode == 0)
            { 
                Bitmap image=createBitmapFromURI(uriOfPicture);
                iv.setImageBitmap(image);
            } 
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,ShowPhoto.class);
            intent.putExtra("uri", uriOfPicture.toString());
            startActivity(intent);
        } 
@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if (uriOfPicture != null) {
            outState.putString("cameraImageUri", uriOfPicture.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("cameraImageUri")) {
            uriOfPicture = Uri.parse(savedInstanceState.getString("cameraImageUri"));
        }
    }
/*********************************** method to take URI of the picture *******************/
public void takeImageFromCamera(){
        String fileName = "new-photo-name.jpg";
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION,
                "Image captured by camera");

        uriOfPicture = getContentResolver()
                .insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        values);  
        Log.i("uri",uriOfPicture.toString());
        Intent intent = new Intent(
                MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriOfPicture);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
        startActivityForResult(intent,
                0);


    }
public Bitmap createBitmapFromURI(Uri uriOfPicture) {

    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getApplicationContext()
                .getContentResolver().openInputStream(uriOfPicture));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (bitmap != null)
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 100, 100, true);
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You should probably do this somewhere else. You can just make a BitMap[] of the size you want and store your images in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a Bitmap array like

```
Bitmap []arr = new Bitmap[size];
```

or you can use a container class like an arraylist if you don't know the size

```
ArrayList<Bitmap> list = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
list.add(reference_to_the_bitmap);
```

Comment: Thanks for the command, I dont get the [size] part yet, could you explain it a bit to me?

Comment: size is just the maximum array size that you want.